# Bootstrap 5 + Angular 12: Javascript does not load

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to install Bootstrap 5 to a Angular 12 project. Everything works fine when importing Bootstrap styles + JS via CDN, but when I try to install ist locally via npm, the Javascript part seems to fail. It seems like the entries in my angular.json file are ignored.

Installation via npm:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Adding the styles works.

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

But when I add the JS file in angular.json, nothing happens - no animations.

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

I've even installed JQuery & Popper (although it should not be needed in Bootstrap 5) and added it to the "scripts" array. No effect. Adding the styles via angular.json also does not work. As soon as I remove it from styles.scss, the styles are gone.

Further note:
I've configured Angular to use SCSS. So I've also tried to import the SCSS styles, but it didn't change anything as well.

It seems like the JS file is being ignored. According to serveral tutorials, this should actually work. Unfortunatly, I'm overseeing something. I'm new to Angular + Bootstrap, so please bear with me if it is something obvious.

Here's the full angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "waiter-view": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/waiter-view",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "waiter-view:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "waiter-view:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "waiter-view:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.scss"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "waiter-view"
}
```

Comment: could you show the whole angluar.json, please?

Comment: “ It seems like the JS file is being ignored.” - what makes you come to this conclusion?

Comment: You have bootstrap scripts only in `test` build, add it to all build configurations.

Comment: It does not load from angular.json at least - neither does the styles path. But it works when I import it directly in the styles.scss. So it seems to me that it doesn't load what I provide in angular.json.

Comment: @izmaylovdev Ha! That's it! Thank you very much, I totally did not see that.

Answer (score 2):

After:

> npm install bootstrap --save

run following command in your command line (for example cmd or Gitbash):

> npm i @popperjs/core

After this command it always works for me.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately didn't solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).